# Next.js CF-IPCountry header to map user to langauge, but breaks Static Site Generation (SSG), how to do it?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, cloudflare

The site is a simple dental clinic site, but have high technical SEO requests (they work with a SEO agency);

Situation:

- Next.js 14
- Cloudflare proxy
- CF-IPCountry header used to map the user to the right language - https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/reference/http-request-headers/#cf-ipcountry automatically
- Multilanguage site in en/fr/de

Goal:
The site should use the maximum of Static Site Generation (SSG); however utilizing `headers()` to depict the country and then the language breaks the SSG. Do you have any suggestions on how to approach the situation best?

Note:

- Usage of [Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server) is not possible, as they are on Vercel.